# BufWritePost not working after navigating using netrw

Tags: vimscript, autocmd, netrw

I'm trying to deploy some static content upon `write`ing a buffer with an autocmd:

```
augroup dep
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWritePost myProject/frontEnd/** :call s:deploy()
augroup END
```

The `s:deploy` function basically does the copy operation.

The `frontEnd` project has a bunch of directories with subdirectories for various JavaScript, CSS, and other files I want to be deployed.

I've found that my autocmd works great when saving files after starting Vim like this:

```
vim myProject/frontEnd/index.html
```

The autocmd also works when saving files after starting Vim like this:

```
vim myProject/frontEnd/js/file.js
```

But, when the autocmd does not execute when I start out at the above `index.html` and then use netrw to navigate to `file.js`. It's like the navigating kills the autocmd.

Any ideas on what is happening here?

**EDIT for future Googlers:**

The solution I was looking for (that @user21497's answer helped me realize) was to use a pre-pending wildcard in my autocmd:

```
autocmd BufWritePost */myProject/frontEnd/** :call s:deploy()
```

Comment: Your autocmd depends on vim being in the directory holding myProject; there are several options that could affect that.  What does :echo g:netrw_keepdir show and what does :echo &acd show, for example.  After navigating, what does :echo getcwd() show?

Comment: @user21497 ah, thanks, your comment helped me realize the issue. I needed to use `*/myProject/frontEnd/**` as my path. If you convert your comment to an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your autocmd depends on vim being in the directory holding myProject; there are several options that could affect that. What does `:echo g:netrw_keepdir` show and what does `:echo &acd` show, for example. After navigating, what does `:echo getcwd()` show?